# Program crashes when deleting dynamic cstring

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, c-strings

I'm working on a school project with the requirement of using dynamically allocated cstrings. In my code I have a temporary cstring but it crashes whenever I try to delete[] it.

Here's my code:

```
#include "group.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void addGroup()
{

    group *newGroup = new group;
    char tempString[ARRAY_CONST];

    cin >> option;
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    if (option == 'Y' || option == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter name: ";

        cin.getline(tempString, ARRAY_CONST, '\n');
        char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString + 1)];
        strcpy(tempName, tempString);

        cout << "Enter email: ";
        cin.getline(tempString, ARRAY_CONST, '\n');

        newGroup->setPromo(true, tempName, tempString);

        delete[] tempName;
    }
}
```

Whenever it reaches "delete[] tempName" the program will crash, could this be a side effect of compiler optimization?

Edited:

I'm not sure how much code I should include without adding too much but here's setPromo():

```
bool group::setPromo(bool enroll, const char *name, const char *email)
{
    promo.enrolled = enroll;

    if (promo.name)
        delete[] promo.name;

    promo.name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy(promo.name, name);

    if (promo.email)
        delete[] promo.email;

    promo.email = new char[strlen(email) + 1];
    strcpy(promo.email, email);

    return true;
}
```

This group class has private data member as so:

```
struct promotion
{
    bool enrolled;
    char *name;
    char *email;
} promo;
```

The group class has a destructor that deals with newGroup.

EDITED AGAIN:

OK I've figure it out but I don't understand why? On the line that contains:

```
char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString + 1)];
```

I've changed that to:

```
char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString) + 1];
```

Where I've taken "1" out of the strlen() parenthesis.

Why would that make a difference? What was happening here?

Comment: I suspect Ninjas attack and kill the allocation in `setPromo`. Prove me wrong by posting a [mcve].

Comment: *I'm not sure how much code I should include without adding too much*. A [mcve] sums it up.

Comment: What's `ARRAY_CONST` ?  Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You have a lot more dynamic action and copying going on than you need. The program allocates `tempName` and copies `tempString` into it. It then allocates storage for `promo.name` and copies `tempName` into it. See the weird here? Best option is to use `std::string`, but if that is out, consider having 2, smartly named, `tempString`s and allocate storage for `promo.name` and `promo.email` and then copy the two `tempString`s. Less allocations less copying.

Comment: I think I'll do that, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously not because of `delete[]`. You need to step into `setPromo`. Finally you missed the `delete newGroup;` at the end of the function.
"dgsomerton" made a good point:

```
char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString + 1)];
```

This actually leads to two bytes less than needed and buffer overrun. A random error is not surprise. Fix to:

```
char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString)+1];
```

This is why I prefer `std::string` over `char*`.

Comment: If I comment out "delete[] tempName" the program won't crash and will continue on, but I'm left with a memory leak.

Comment: Runtime errors have evil behaviours; the symptoms often appear too late. Nothing more can be said unless 'setPromo' is analyzed. Though not logical, I guess that function may even be deleting the pointer.

Comment: this code is wrong "char *tempName = new char[strlen(tempString + 1)];" it will take the address of tempString add 1 to that address, and perform a strlen() on that address. The answer will be some random number (potentially smaller than required), so you write into unallocated memory, potentially corrupting your heap.